# rcdimple facet function subplot labels

Tags: r, facet, dimple.js

I am using `rcdimple` to create a set of faceted barplots based on a categorical column. The plots are coming out as expected but I cannot figure out how to apply a label to each subplot.

In the example below I have commented out some of the options I have tried:

```
fake.data <- read.table(sep=',', header=T, text="
    category,variable,value,count
    A Category,SITE.ACTIVITIES,1,51
    A Category,SITE.ACTIVITIES,2,116
    A Category,SITE.ACTIVITIES,3,46
    A Category,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,1,17
    A Category,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,2,111
    A Category,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,3,93
    All Others,SITE.ACTIVITIES,1,60
    All Others,SITE.ACTIVITIES,2,37
    All Others,SITE.ACTIVITIES,3,54
    All Others,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,1,80
    All Others,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,2,167
    All Others,PROXIMITY.TO.RECEPTORS,3,120
    ")



plt <- fake.data %>%
    dimple(x ="value", y = "count", 
           #title = c('A Category','All Others'),
           groups = 'category', type = "bar", 
           width = 900, height = 220) %>%
        facet('variable', 
              #title = c('A Category','All Others'),
              removeAxes = T) %>%
        default_colors(c('blue','grey')) %>%
        xAxis(type = "addCategoryAxis", 
              #facet.title = c('A Category','All Others'),
              orderRule = "value") %>%
        yAxis(overrideMax=300, ticks=4) %>%
        add_legend() %>%
        add_title(text = c('A Category','All Others'))
```

[image]

After seeing figure 2.14 in [this](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/3/18/week-11-dimple-as-htmlwidget) blog post I have added the following:

```
plt$x$options$tasks <- list(htmlwidgets::JS('
  function(){
       //this.widgetDimple should hold our chart
       var chart1 = this.widgetDimple[0];
       var chart2 = this.widgetDimple[1];
       chart1.svg.append("text")
       .attr("x", chart1.axes[0]._scale(3) )
       .attr("y", chart1.axes[1]._scale(300) )
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("A Category")
       chart2.svg.append("text")
       .attr("x", chart2.axes[0]._scale(3) )
       .attr("y", chart2.axes[1]._scale(300) )
       .attr("dy", "0.6em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("All Others")
       }
       '))
plt
```

I think I am on the right path but think there is probably a cleaner way to do this (sorry my javascript is not great).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be to add text via `svg.append("text")` as outlined above. The `rcdimple` facet function creates an array of chart objects one for each subplot. In turn each subplot contains the information needed for each label accessible via `OBJECT.data[0].variable`.

The solution presented below will work for any number of facet chart objects. The numbers `1` and `350` relate to the x and y position of the labels related to the x and y axis values. These would need to be modified for different datasets

```
plt <- fake.data %>%
        dimple(x ="value", y = "count", 
               groups = 'category', type = "bar", 
               width = 900, height = 220) %>%
            facet('variable',removeAxes = T) %>%
            default_colors(c('blue','grey')) %>%
            xAxis(type = "addCategoryAxis",orderRule = "value") %>%
            yAxis(overrideMax=300, ticks=4) %>%
            add_legend() %>%
            add_title(text = 'Plot Title')


plt$x$options$tasks <- list(htmlwidgets::JS(sprintf('
    function(){
        var n = this.widgetDimple.length
        var variables = {};
        var subs = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) subs.push("c"+i)
        for( var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var v = subs[i];
            variables[v] = this.widgetDimple[i]
            variables[v].svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", variables[v].axes[0]._scale(%s) )
            .attr("y", variables[v].axes[1]._scale(%s) )
            .attr("text-anchor", "left")
            .text(variables[v].data[0].variable)
        };
    }
    ', 1, 350)))
plt
```

There may be a more elegant solution, my JS is not great. Thanks to authors of the [rcdimple](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/rcdimple) package and the examples given [here](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/3/18/week-11-dimple-as-htmlwidget)

[image]